# In TYPO3 6.1, how to debug why CType is not rendering at all

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

In one of my TYPO3 6.1 sites, when I insert a content element of the CType "menu" ("Menü/Sitemap"), this is simply not rendered in the frontend. If I choose another CType, the item is output.

I have checked in the TSOB, tt_content.menu is there (css_styled_content is included).

Also, it is in the right column which is rendered via csc.

```
temp.maincontent < styles.content.get
temp.maincontent {
  select.where = colPos = 0
  wrap = <div class="maintext">|</div>
  // required = 1
}
```

How could I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a weird issue with multiple backend layouts, being rendered in various parts of the `PAGE` COA. I've solved it by avoiding multiple use of the same temp. object, defining one `temp.homecontent` and one `temp.standardcontent` so they are not conflicting anymore.

To answer my own question "how to debug this": Well, by debugging.

I disabled all my TS includes and created the most basic kind of site: `page = PAGE` and `page.10 < styles.content.get`. With this setup, the CType menu was appearing. So I tried continuing by adding each TS template and then, when it stopped working, by adding / removing `temp.`item by `temp`item from the corresponding template. Until I found the conflicting part. Fairly basic. But as there were no errors or similar hints in TSOB, probably the only way.